# Reformat For Loop Table

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID   Covid_pos  Asymptomatic  Fever  Cough ...
0          1             0      1      0
1          0             0      0      1
2          1             1      0      1
3          1             0      1      0
4          0             1      1      0
5          1             0      1      0
6          0             1      1      0
7          1             0      0      1
8          0             0      0      0
9          0             0      0      0
```

I wrote a for loop which produces the following output for each symptom variable and the outcome variable, 'COVID_POS'.

```
exposure=['Cough',"Nasal_Congestion","Wheezing_Asthma","Abdominal_Pain","Diarrhea","Vomiting","Rash","Fever","MED_ALERT_CPR_SHOCK_SEPSIS","Lymph_Node_Neck","Ear","Mouth Sores","Eye","SOB_WOB_Hyp_Desat","PNA","Nausea","Weak_Fatigue","Bodyaches","Dizziness","Fussy","Poor_PO_Dehydration","Tachycardia","COVID Exposure","COVID Test","COVID PUI" ,"COVID MIS","COVID Kawasaki","CP","ST","HA","Loss_Taste_Smell"]

for symptom in exposure:
    CTab=pd.crosstab(LABS_TAT[symptom],LABS_TAT.Covid_pos)
    Odds = sm.stats.Table2x2(CTab)
    print(Odds.summary())

OUTPUT:
```

[image]

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:** The output is correct but I would like to reformat it so it looks like the table below:

```
Symptom            Odds Ratio   LCB   UCB 
Cough              2.607       1.981 3.430
Nasal_Congestion   1.899       1.226 2.941  
Wheezing_Asthma    0.739       0.373 1.46
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from [the source](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/stats/contingency_tables.html#Table2x2.summary) that the first line of the summary is constructed from the `oddsratio_confint`, `oddsratio_pvalue` methods and the `oddsratio` attribute. Construct a dictionary to turn into a DataFrame.

```
d = {'Symptom':[],'Odds Ratio':[],'LCB':[],'UCB':[]}
for symptom in exposure:
    CTab=pd.crosstab(LABS_TAT[symptom],LABS_TAT.Covid_pos)
    Odds = sm.stats.Table2x2(CTab)
    d['Symptom'].append(symptom)
    d['Odds Ratio'].append(Odds.oddsratio)
    lcb,ucb = Odds.oddsratio_confint()
    d['LCB'].append(lcb)
    d['UCB'].append(ucb)

results = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: thanks - just a minor code tweak:"""   'UCB':[]} """

Comment: @Raven I can't help thinking there is a better way to get the crosstab stats without the for loop but I really don't know anything about statsmodel.